# LDAP Query with sub result

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

I have been banging my head for quite a while with this and can't get it to work. I have a LDAP Query I do have working in AD Users and Computers but dont know how to do it programatically in C#.

Here are my LDAP Query that works fine in the AD Tool: (memberOf=CN=AccRght,OU=Groups,OU=P,OU=Server,DC=mydomain,DC=com)(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(l=City)

I have used this code to get the user accounts to get members of CN=AccRght but I'm not succeeding on limiting users belonging to a specific city.

```
public StringCollection GetGroupMembers(string strDomain, string strGroup)
{
    StringCollection groupMemebers = new StringCollection();
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + strDomain + ",DC=com");
        DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher("(CN=" + strGroup + ")");
        SearchResultCollection coll = srch.FindAll();
        foreach (SearchResult rs in coll)
        {
            ResultPropertyCollection resultPropColl = rs.Properties;
            foreach( Object memberColl in resultPropColl["member"])
            {
                DirectoryEntry gpMemberEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + memberColl);
                System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection userProps = gpMemberEntry.Properties;
                object obVal = userProps["sAMAccountName"].Value;
                if (null != obVal)
                {
                    groupMemebers.Add(obVal.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    return groupMemebers;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?  LDAP may not be necessary, in favour of using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace.

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5. I will have a look at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, looks interesting!

Comment: DirectoryServices.AccountManagement way more easy to work with and for me much more logical. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, basically all you need is to transfer that LDAP filter you're using in the tool into your DirectorySearcher - something like this:

```
public StringCollection GetGroupMembers(string strDomain, string strGroup)
{
    StringCollection groupMemebers = new StringCollection();

    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry ent = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=" + strDomain + ",DC=com");

        DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher();

        // build the LDAP filter from your (CN=strGroup) part that you had
        // in the constructor, plus that filter you used in the AD tool
        // to "AND" those together, use the LDAP filter syntax:
        //  (&(condition1)(condition2))  
        srch.Filter = string.Format("(&(CN={0})(memberOf=CN=AccRght,OU=Groups,OU=P,OU=Server,DC=mydomain,DC=com)(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(l=City))", strGroup);

        SearchResultCollection coll = srch.FindAll();

        foreach (SearchResult rs in coll)
        {
            ResultPropertyCollection resultPropColl = rs.Properties;

            foreach( Object memberColl in resultPropColl["member"])
            {
                DirectoryEntry gpMemberEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + memberColl);
                System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection userProps = gpMemberEntry.Properties;
                object obVal = userProps["sAMAccountName"].Value;
                if (null != obVal)
                {
                    groupMemebers.Add(obVal.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    return groupMemebers;
}
```

That should apply that filter to your search, e.g. you should now only get back users for that specific city.

Definitely check out this MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) - excellent intro to S.DS.AM ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually looking for a way to recursively enumerate group members, maybe you need to use the recursive version of memberof (which you can achieve by using the `(memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(cn=Group1,OU=groupsOU,DC=x)))` syntax).

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(VS.85).aspx